# Vue.Js v-bind:class does not add class on click

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm quite new to Vue.js and have been using it in work the last number of weeks. I've been asked to do a small update to existing code but cannot get v-bind:class working correctly.
In my simplified example, if a button is clicked, the other classes should become less prominent, i.e.

- If 'Colour' is clicked anything with the class 'sound' or 'shape' reduce in opacity
- If 'Shape' is clicked anything with the class 'colour or 'sound' reduce in opacity
- If 'Sound' is clicked anything with the class 'colour' or 'shape reduce in opacity

Of course, two buttons shouldn't be selected at the same time as can happen in my example, selecting say, 'Shape' after previously selecting 'Colour' should undo the opacity from the class 'shape' and add to the necessary classes.

Whats happening though is that only the 'Sound' button is functioning correctly... 'Colour' does nothing and 'Shape' only half works!

I know I could use JavaScript to write a method to alter the DOM by getting the elementByClassName but I would like to stick to using Vue correctly (if it is possible)

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    colourAddClass: false,
    shapeAddClass: false,
    soundAddClass: false,
  }
})
```

```css
.opacity {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.colour {
  color: blue;
}

.shape {
  color: red;
}

.sound {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <button @click="colourAddClass = !colourAddClass"> Colours </button>
    <button @click="shapeAddClass = !shapeAddClass"> Shapes </button>
    <button @click="soundAddClass = !soundAddClass"> Sounds </button>
    <br/><br/>
    <span class="colour" v-bind:class="{'opacity': shapeAddClass, 'opacity': soundAddClass}">Yellow</span>
    <span class="shape" v-bind:class="{'opacity': colourAddClass, 'opacity': soundAddClass}">Triangle</span>
    <span class="sound" v-bind:class="{'opacity': colourAddClass, 'opacity': shapeAddClass}">Woof</span>
    <span class="shape" v-bind:class="{'opacity': colourAddClass, 'opacity': soundAddClass}">Circle</span>
    <br/>
    <span class="sound" v-bind:class="{'opacity': colourAddClass, 'opacity': shapeAddClass}">Meow</span>
    <span class="colour" v-bind:class="{'opacity': shapeAddClass, 'opacity': soundAddClass}">Purple</span>
    <span class="shape" v-bind:class="{'opacity': colourAddClass, 'opacity': soundAddClass}">Circle</span>
    <span class="colour" v-bind:class="{'opacity': shapeAddClass, 'opacity': soundAddClass}">Orange</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Try instead of creating two entries for 'opacity' in each class binding, using && and || to state when the class should be added and when removed.
For example, "{'opacity': colourAddClass || shapeAddClass}"
It'll be easier to debug.

Comment: or uses one computed property to determinate the opacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish these types of tasks with VueJS. Below is one way. I'm sure others have shorter methods. To explain my method, I am using a single variable to track the current active button. I use a method to set that variable since we want to toggle on and off. I then bind the class attribute to some logic.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    active: null
  },
  methods: {
    toggleActive( type ) {
        //if active is already of this type, set to null
        this.active = ( this.active == type ) ? null : type;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.opacity {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.colour {
  color: blue;
}

.shape {
  color: red;
}

.sound {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
    <button @click="toggleActive('colour')"> Colours </button>
    <button @click="toggleActive('shape')"> Shapes </button>
    <button @click="toggleActive('sound')"> Sounds </button>
    <br/><br/>
    <span :class="{ colour: true, opacity: active && active != 'colour' }" >Yellow</span>
    <span :class="{ shape: true, opacity: active && active != 'shape' }">Triangle</span>
    <span :class="{ sound: true, opacity: active && active != 'sound' }">Woof</span>
    <span :class="{ shape: true, opacity: active && active != 'shape' }">Circle</span>
    <br/>
    <span :class="{ sound: true, opacity: active && active != 'sound' }">Meow</span>
    <span :class="{ colour: true, opacity: active && active != 'colour' }">Purple</span>
    <span :class="{ shape: true, opacity: active && active != 'shape' }">Circle</span>
    <span :class="{ colour: true, opacity: active && active != 'colour' }">Orange</span>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```